# the historical present and past are alternately used

Tags: historical-present

I just now read this following paragraph about the historical present. Why does the author use the past and present alternately?

> As we were entering the diner, a homeless man came up to us. He **looks** around at us and **says**, “Do you have any coins?” When John replied, “If we gave you coins, what were you going to do with them,” he **says**, “Well, when I have enough, I was going to buy something to eat at that gas station across the street.” Then John replied, “You know what, I think our boss wants you to join us. Could we invite you to come in and dine with us?” His eyes **open** a bit wider and he **says**, “Really? Who’s your boss?” So John told him, “His name is Jesus.”

Does this mean in the midst of describing a past event in the past tense, you can switch to the historical present whenever and wherever you wish?

Comment: Where did you read this? Is it by a professional writer? I would use either historical present or past tense consistently.

Comment: I forget where. On some website about historical present.

Comment: It's full of grammar mistakes, even beyond the shifting tenses. I wouldn't bother learning from that website.

Comment: https://www.bibleversestudy.com/historical-present-tense.htm

Answer (score 1):

**Sort of. Maybe. It depends.**

The author appears to consistently write John in past tense, and the homeless man in historical present. I can only assume that there is some literary or symbolic reason for doing this, as it would make very little sense otherwise. In *spoken* English, this sort of thing is much more common and less remarkable, but written English follows different rules, and generally sticks with simple past unless there's a good reason to use a different tense. From the short extract you have quoted, I can't see what that reason might be, but that doesn't mean there is no such reason. If I had to guess, I would assume that the past tense has something to do with John's religious beliefs or practices (given his mention of Jesus), and the present is in some way representative of the homeless man's more mundane, earthly concerns about being able to feed himself, but it's difficult to determine if this is correct without seeing more of the work.

In general, fiction has a greater degree of freedom to break grammatical rules than non-fiction. In this case, the author "gets away with it" because the sentence structure is simple enough that there is no ambiguity about the order in which events happened, and (as discussed above) there is presumably some reason for switching tenses. There is no hard and fast rule that you must use the same [tense-aspect-mood (TAM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense%E2%80%93aspect%E2%80%93mood) combination throughout an entire paragraph, but neither is it wise to randomly change TAMs for no reason. Each possible TAM imparts a distinct set of connotations on your writing, and you need to consider which of those connotations are most appropriate for each sentence, as well as how each sentence should relate to those surrounding it.

In the case of historical present vs. simple past, the connotations are roughly as follows:

- Formal historical present (e.g. "Of the Categorical Imperative, [Kant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant) writes...") carries a sense of timelessness, in which we "don't care" exactly when an event happened (in the example sentence, we care more about Kant's argument than about when he wrote it). Simple past connotes an event that took place at a specific point in time, although that point may not be explicitly described.
- When historical present is used to describe one or more concrete events or actions, which must have taken place at some specific point in time, it is more likely to be interpreted as informal or "conversational" - it "feels" more like the narrator is a person telling a story, and less like a disembodied observer passively relating what has transpired. Simple past can also be informal, but the tense does not connote informality all by itself. Informal historical present is more likely to appear in spoken English than written English, in part because speech tends to be less formal than writing, and in part because simple past is ubiquitous in written English, especially in fiction. However, you can find this informal historical present in plenty of written examples, especially in contexts where the author wants to give the narrator more of a personality or role in the story.
- The mixture of the two tenses seen in your quote is not common. It is more typical to choose one or the other, and perhaps mix in some other aspects and moods if necessary (such as continuous or perfect). This is why I found it difficult to guess what exactly the author was trying to accomplish.